# PHP XPath Child Concat And New Line Issues

Tags: php, dom, xpath

I am using DOMXPath to query nodes in an HTML document which content I would like to extract.

I have the following HTML document:

```
<p class="data">
    Immediate Text
    <br>
    Text In Second Line
    <br>
    E-Mail:
    <script>Some Script Tag</script>
    <a href="#">
        <script>Another Script Tag</script>
        Some Link In Third Line
    </a>
    <br>
    Text In Last Line
</p>
```

I would like to receive the following result:

> Immediate Text\r\nText In Second Line\r\nE-Mail: Some Link In Third Line\r\nText In Last Line

So far I have the following PHP code:

```
#...
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$dom = new \DOMDocument();
if(!$dom->loadHTML($html)) {
    #...
}

$xpath = \DOMXPath($dom);
$result = $xpath->query("(//p[@class='data'])[1]/text()[not(parent::script)]");
```

Problems:

- It does not include the child nodes' texts.
- It does not include line breaks.

Answer (score 0):

By using child axis `/` in `/text()` you'll get only direct child of current node context. To get all descendants, use descendant axis (`//`) instead.

To get both text node and `<br>`, you can try using `//nodes()` axis and filter further by *node's type* -to get nodes of type text node- or *name* -to get elements named `br`- :

```
(//p[@class='data'])[1]//nodes()[self::text() or self:br][not(parent::script)]
```

Comment: I tried using it but it doesn't find anything. (//p[@class='data'])[1] works. With //nodes() it doesn't find anything. Do you have an idea why? Also: (//p[@class='data'])[1]//text() also just includes the first line.

Comment: @Chris. hmm.. not sure, worked for me in an xpath tester. I'm not fluent in PHP, but seems to be working for me here also : [php codepad](http://missingbrackets.com/codepad/editor/0sKw2v). If you could reproduce the problem there, I or somebody else may be able to help

Comment: Oh, thanks. It works, yes. However, I seem to have the problem that the website I'm querying builds/renders the a-tag from a document.write()-JavaScript call. So I have a document.write()-JavaScript part in my DOMDocument-structure that I need to run before I can query it so that I can query the link (a-tag) in the document. Is that in any way possible?

Comment: Hi @Chris., the topic is getting away from xpath now, so I can't answer precisely. In some other platform I know (C#/python), executing javascript would require a library that simulate browsers (for example: Selenium), I really don't know if PHP capable of doing this without such library.