# PHP+XPath - Get node text including <br>, without child nodes content

Tags: php, xpath

I have this in my html (multiple instances of the following):

```
<div id='message'>
    This is the first line<br />
    This is the second line
    <a href='link'>link_A</a>
</div>
```

I want to get this:

```
This is the first line<br />This is the second line
```

Using

```
$messages = $xpath->query('//div[@id="message"]/text()');
```

I am getting

> This is the first line

and

> This is the second line

as separate nodes.

As per another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29870772/php-xpath-child-concat-and-new-line-issues) I tried

```
$xpath->query('//div[@id="message"][self::text() or self:br]');
AND
$xpath->query('//div[@id="message"]//nodes[self::text() or self:br]');
```

But that gives and 'Invalid Expression' error.

Can someone help me out with what I'm doing wrong here?

Thanks.

Comment: `</br>` is illegal html. `<br>` is a singleton tag and has no content, nor a  closing tag. `<br />`  is the only valid form. and since you are asking for `text()`, you're getting just that.. the TEXT in the child nodes. you probably want `innerHTML`, which isn't directly supported by php dom.

Comment: My mistake it should be <br />. Thanks, I corrected it.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the `node()` but excluding the `a` element:

```
//div[@id="message"]/node()[not(self::a)]
```

Demo (using [`xmllint`](http://xmlsoft.org/xmllint.html)):

```
$ cat test.html
<div id='message'>
    This is the first line<br/>
    This is the second line
    <a href='link'>link_A</a>
</div>
$ xmllint test.html --xpath '//div[@id="message"]/node()[not(self::a)]'
This is the first line<br/>
This is the second line
```

Comment: Using that when I do: foreach($all_posts as $post){echo $post->nodeValue;}.    I get "This is the first line This is the second line". How can I get the line break too?